# Getting a vertex_handle from an edge_iterator

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I'm having quite some difficulty getting a vertex_handle for each of the end points of an edge in a Delaunay triangulation. Since I hammered my head against this for several hours I thought maybe one of you guys could help me out with this apparently trivial problem:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>

using namespace std;

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Triangulation;
typedef Triangulation::Point Point;
typedef Triangulation::Edge_iterator Edge_iterator;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex;

int main(){
  Point p;
  Triangulation t;
  while(cin >> p)
    t.insert(p);

  // Iterate over edges
  for(Edge_iterator ei=t.finite_edges_begin();ei!=t.finite_edges_end(); ei++){
    // Get a vertex from the edge
    Vertex vs = ei->source();
  }
}
```

According to the documentation dereferencing an Edge_iterator I should get an Edge_handle and Edge_handle should have members source() and target() to simply get the endpoints, but it won't compile and seems to be wrong. Derefencing like above will give me a pair<> which doesn't have those member functions.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the compilation failing?

Comment: It's that (ei*) is of type pair which obviously does not have a source().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dereferencing an `Edge_iterator` will give you an `Edge` according to the [documentation](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/TDS_2_ref/Concept_TriangulationDataStructure_2.html#Cross_link_anchor_1307).

`Edge` is definded as follows: `typedef std::pair<Face_handle,int> Edge;`

Dereferencing the `Face_handle` will give you a [Face](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/TDS_2_ref/Concept_TriangulationDataStructure_2--Face.html#Cross_link_anchor_1309).

The two vertices that the edge joins can be accessed by:

```
  for(Edge_iterator ei=t.finite_edges_begin();ei!=t.finite_edges_end(); ei++){
    // Get a vertex from the edge
    Triangulation::Face& f = *(ei->first);
    int i = ei->second;
    Vertex vs = f.vertex(f.cw(i));
    Vertex vt = f.vertex(f.ccw(i));
  }
```

I don't know if it is helpful for you quest, but is access the points like this:

```
for (Edge_iterator it = m_tri.edges_begin(); it != m_tri.edges_end(); ++it)
{
    Triangulation::Segment seg = m_tri.segment( *it );

    Triangulation::Point p0 = seg.point(0);
    Triangulation::Point p1 = seg.point(1);
    // ...
}
```

The CGAL documentation is confusing to me... I am curious where you found the `eh->source()` and `eh->target()` calls, I could not find it :-)

Comment: It should be handles rather than vertices in your first solution `Vertex_handle vs` and `Vertex_handle vt`.

Comment: tangentially related: So the most direct way to get the adjacent faces for an `Edge_iterator` would be to dereference it, then dereference the `Face_handle` to get one face, and then find the index of the edge to finally get it with `neighbor(index)` ? Edit: Just found [mirror_edge](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_2/classTriangulationDataStructure__2.html#afe6bc558fc5653ebebc0a162bc37734b) which makes this a tad easier